# No resource identifier found for attribute 'lable' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, netbeans

I am facing this error when compiling android project using netbeans.

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'lable' in package 'android'

I can't figure out what's wrong as I'm following a tutorial and it works on that.

this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:lable="@string/app_label"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: Use `android:label` instead of `android:lable`

Comment: seem to get the same error but now in AndroidManifest.xml everytime I compile the project it changes itself back to `lable`

Comment: try to clean project before compiling

Answer (score 1):

`android:lable` does not exist, use `android:label` instead:

```
android:label="@string/app_label"
```